# Launcher ubuntu touch

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch

I m left hand I was thinking if it s possible to move the launcher on the right and side of the screen ?
sometime it s a bit weird to use it with the left thumb on the left and side of the phone
it s would be great for the market as well i guess :)
Would be very nice to have an option for choosing in which side you want the launcher

Thank you

Comment: Not sure what your question for the community would be. This sounds rather like a feature request to me. Maybe you could try to suggest your idea? I guess here could be the correct place: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/

Comment: It's not a request honestly because I think I m not the only left hand in the world that use or will use the device :)   I post the question here because I think the people on launchpad are around here as well